# How to stop elements from moving when another element is hidden in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm using the Netbeans IDE to create a GUI. The GUI looks great when all elements are visible, however, when I hide some of the elements, everything else moves as well. Is there any way to stop this from happening? I don't think there is any relevant code, but let me know if I should add some.

[Screenshot of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9u2J.png)

Comment: Short answer is, no. Longer answer is, use "dummy" place holders in the place of components which are invisible

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the reply, do you know of anywhere that I  can find information about dummy place holders and how to use them in Netbeans?

Comment: A "dummy" place holder can be any component (`JPanel` for example) which can be used to occupy the same space as the other component